# Problem connecting INA114 with LM331 for voltage to frequency conversion

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, load-cell, vf-fv-converter

i'm actually using a load cell and i would like to send the load cell information to an android tablet through jack audio.
Then load cell caracteristics are presented here: http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?product_id=3134

I'm using first an instrumentation amplifier, INA114 with a 1000 gain, to amplify load cell output and it works fine.

[image]

The second step is to build a voltage/frequency conversion with LM331.

[image]

When i test the V-F circuit with a variable DC supply it works fine  but when connected to INA's, the output of V-F converter saturates (directly to 5v) and i don't know why.

Did anybody have the same problem; any help would be really useful

Comment: What range of output voltages do you get out of your INA114? Do they change when you connect it up to the LM331 circuit?

Comment: What @brhans asked.  Do you monitor the voltage of the INA output as you connect it?  What about if you put some load (10-100k) on the INA output?  (How is the load cell and INA powered?  It doesn't look like the INA114 has a input range that goes all the way to the negative supply rail. http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina114.pdf

Comment: @brhans thanks for the reply the voltage range is 0-5v, the load cell is giving a maximum voltage of 5mv and with a 1000 gain, we have 5V. The INA's output voltage doesn't change when connected to the LM331 circuitry

Comment: @GeorgeHerold The load cell is powered with 5V DC and INA with +5/-5V. I tried to connect a load on INA's output; i was using trimmers (4k7 and 10k) but unfortunately i didn't have results

Comment: OK that's good.  Is the INA refernce gnd connected to the LM331 gnd?

Comment: Yes all grounds are connected